# For fun puzzle has me stumped on a book cipher

Tags: classical-cipher

So originally a puzzle was given out to a community i'm a part of and what was given was this.

. .. . ... . . . . . . . ... . .. . . . . . .. . ... . . . . . .... . .. . . . . . .. .. .. . . . . . .. . . . . .. ..... . . . . . .. .. ..... . . . . . .. . . . . . . . .... . . . . . . . . . . . . . .... . . . . . .. . . . . . . . ... .. .... . . . . . ....

https://apeiron.iulm.it/retrieve/handle/10808/4129/46589/Machiavelli%2C%20The%20Prince.pdf

I've tried a few of the common book cipher decoding steps. Line - word - letter, because it just so happens that the dots when converted to numbers can be broken up into 3 numbers or 4 numbers perfectly.

1213 1111 1113 1211 1112 1311 1114 1211 1112 2211 1112 1111 2511 1112 2511 1112 1111 1114 1111 1111 1111 1411 1112 1111 1113 2411 1114

or

121 311 111 113 121 111 121 311 111 412 111 112 221 111 121 111 251 111 122 511 111 211 111 114 111 111 111 111 141 111 121 111 111 324 111 114

I noticed though there is a lot of repeating locations and i'm not quite sure if this is correct even. Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Its been stumping me for a month or so now.

Also with the 4 numbers every 3rd number is a 1. Not sure if this means anything.